# Remove a string from a list of list

Tags: python

I am trying to remove a string from a list of list while keeping the internal list.

Example:

**Input**

```
x = [["banana", "dog", "potato"], ["dog", "potato"], ["banana"], ["dog", "potato"]]
```

I use a function

```
x.remove_from_internal_lists("banana") # Invented function
```

**Output I would like:**

```
x = [["dog", "potato"], ["dog", "potato"], ["dog", "potato"]]
```

I know about `.remove()` and other methods on a single list but I am not sure how to use them to remove a string and keep the inside lists.

Comment: loop through and remove the string from sub lists

Comment: remove_from_internal_lists should iterate over each internal list, test to see if the target item is in the target internal list, and remove it if it is - Ha!  @SuperStew beat me to the punch.

Comment: have you tried anything yourself before asking to write code for you?

Comment: Can your list have repeated values like `['dog', 'dog', 'banana']`?

Comment: Yes, they can have repeated value but there will be not the case because in the original list there are no repeated value in the inner lists

Comment: If the nesting level is likely to vary, you can take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list-comprehension:

```
lst = [["banana", "dog", "potato"], ["dog", "potato"], ["banana"], ["dog", "potato"]]

lst = [[y for y in x if y != 'banana'] for x in lst if x != ['banana']]
# [['dog', 'potato'], ['dog', 'potato'], ['dog', 'potato']]
```

Comment: The OP said he/she wants to keep the original lists I think

Comment: @Steve wouldn't the original list be maintained as `lst` and the altered list as `output`??

Comment: @Steve, both input and output says `x = ..`, so replace original maybe?

Comment: And what if we do not know what the initial item to remove is? What if each list item is different..?

Comment: sorry folks.  forget my comment.  misread question - upvoted ypercy

Comment: @GerhardBarnard, 1. there is no case like you don't know what to remove. 2. Does not matter what the list contains.

Comment: Austin you should refactor the answer to for in line with his question. They have a fair point. And you should know it's bad practice to change the values of a list that you are iterating

Comment: list comprehensions should be short and readable, this is not readable at all

Comment: @Swift, disagree on the bad practice. There is no wrong in iterating over list and modifying unless you are removing anything using `pop` or `remove`. Here it's creating a new list from an already existing list by checking conditions.

Comment: Not quite. I know i want to remove the first item only whether banana or avocado.

Comment: You have a fair point there Austin, but I'm not accusing you of bad practice, but rather stating that it is bad practice to *change the values of a list during iteration*. I agree that creating a mew list with the same variable name is essentially the same as doing it with another variable, except that it will reduce the overhead on bigger datasets

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate over each list in `x`, and check to see if the value is in the sublist. If it is, remove it. If not, continue.

```
def remove_from_internal_lists(l, value):
    for y in l:
        if value in y:
            y.remove(value)
    return [x for x in l if x]  # removes any empty lists
```

and call it like

```
>>> new_x = remove_from_internal_lists(x, "banana")
>>> new_x
[['dog', 'potato'], ['dog', 'potato'], ['dog', 'potato']]
```

Comment: Author doesn't want an empty list, he wants the entire list removed

Comment: @LukeNing yup, updated my function when I saw OP's expected output and forgot to edit the sample

Answer (score 2):

Other answers have covered how to replicate this behavior, but the way to add functions to a type is to subclass:

```
class NestedList(list):
    def remove_from_internal_lists(self, word):
        forward_final_index = len(self) - 1
        for reversed_index, sub_list in enumerate(reversed(self)):
            if isinstance(sub_list, list) and word in sub_list:
                if len(sub_list) == 1:
                    # Modifying a list under iteration is normally a Bad Idea(tm):
                    # This is possible because we are iterating in reverse which
                    # guarantees all invalidated indices have already been processed
                    # and allows for multiple copies of [word] in our outer list.
                    # Additionally, we preserve any empty lists already present
                    del self[forward_final_index - reversed_index]
                else:
                    sub_list.remove(word)
```

*Note: That large comment is **necessary**: you're doing something that is normally a Bad Idea<sup>tm</sup> and should explain yourself so future maintainers (including yourself) aren't misled.*

This allows us to use your "Invented function", and NestedLists will act in every way like lists plus:

```
>>> lst = [["banana", "dog", "potato"], ["dog", "potato"], ["banana"], ["dog", "potato"]]
>>> nlst = NestedList(lst)
>>> nlst.remove_from_internal_lists("banana")
>>> nlst
[['dog', 'potato'], ['dog', 'potato'], ['dog', 'potato']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using recursion that works with any depth of nesting in the lists, and also removes all occurrences of the specified item in case of duplicates. Also works with "hybrid" lists that consist of a mix of inner lists and non-lists:

```
def remove_from_inner_lists(the_list, the_item):
    for e in reversed(the_list):
        if (type(e)) == list:
            remove_from_inner_lists(e, the_item)
        elif e == the_item:
            the_list.remove(e)
```

**Output:**

```
x = [[["banana", "dog", "potato"], ["dog", "potato"], "banana"], ["banana"], ["dog", "potato"]]

remove_from_inner_lists(x, "banana")

print (x)

[[['dog', 'potato'], ['dog', 'potato']], [], ['dog', 'potato']]
```